# How to load prebuilt reusable Vuejs components through http without knowing its URL beforehand?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-dynamic-components

I have the following setup:

I have two prebuilt VueJs apps under those URLs (dev + prod) served through Apache :

```
https://dev-domain.com/web
https://prod-domain.com/kiosk
```

These are general VueJs apps that need to include the same games implemented in VueJs and have them embedded

I have a backend implementation that serves a single file vuejs game that was built like:

`yarn vue-cli-service build --target wc --name game ./src/components/Game.vue`

and will be served like:

```
https://dev-domain.com/assets/games/{id}/game.js 
https://prod-domain.com/assets/games/{id}/game.js
```

I have an endpoint for saving progress of a player on each game e.g:

```
https://dev-domain.com/api/v1/games/{id}/save
https://prod-domain.com/api/v1/games/{id}/save
```

Each time, different games are active based on current date - so I don't know the actual urls of the game assets to be fetched beforehand. I will be asking my backend api to see which ones are active like this:

```
https://dev-domain.com/api/v1/games/active
https://prod-domain.com/api/v1/games/active
```

I am looking into [http-vue-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader), [Distributed Vue.js Applications Part 1: Loading Components via HTTP](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/), [How to Implement Dynamic Components on Vuejs](https://towardsdatascience.com/dynamic-components-vuejs-13c3e70431cc)  and other options but I am not sure if it is possible to have dynamic URLs. Also I don't know what is the best way to approach this problem.

How can this be implemented in the simplest possible way?

Comment: For Vue3, you can try https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader and provide a customized file loader (disclaimer: author here)